# Wordpress how to determine what page a post is on a paginated list

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a link to the individual post template which returns the correct page in a paginated post list, e.g if the post appears on page 3, then the link should send the user back to page 3.

Also worth noting is this is a custom WP_Query as it's actually a custom post type.

My code looks like this currently:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 11 ); ?>">Back to posts</a>
```

(11 id the id of the page with the post list)

I don't want to use a simple javascript back because they may not have come from the list page, or even from the site at all.

Comment: Do you want to display previous post link?

Comment: I don't think a previous post link is appropriate in my specific case, I want a link that takes the user back to the post list

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, but it is one way that would work.
You need to get the pagenumber the post is on. To do that, you would need to loop all the posts (with the custom query you use for the original pagination) and have a counter (and then break the loop when the post is found). Then divide that number by the total number of pages. Use ceil() to get the next highest integer. That is the page number the post is on.

Then save that number in a post meta for that post ID, because you do not want this calculation on each post view. Save it on saving a post. BUT, you will need to recalc every post on saving or making 1 new post. So this will not be nice for your server.

If you have any kind of caching, this will not really work, unless the caching caches everything at the same time each time.

Anyway, I would not do this myself. Just use back with JS and take for granted that this does not work for visitors coming to the post directly.